# Jersey 2.x Example with Eclipse - ClassNotFound

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

Trying to run a simple example using the following:

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE 2.0.2
- Tomcat 7.0
- Java SE Runtime 1.7.0_55-b14
- Jersey 2.10.1

Added all files from lib, ext, and api folders in Jersey download zip to WEB-INF/lib.

Addd the following to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>test.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Added the following to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Getting the following exception when running the project:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you deploying it inside eclipse? If that is the case, regardless of your pom.xml, you've got to include your dependencies in eclipse's "Run configuration".